# Lightning Component expectedFields issue - Summer 2019

Tags: lightning-aura-components

A very simple LC is giving me some serious issues, at random - example:

Looks like there's a problem.

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
>   continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
>   shown here and any other related details. Missing field(s) :
>   '{"expectedFields":["Contact.Id","Contact.Name","Contact.RecordTypeId","Contact.Address_1_H__c","Contact.Address_2_H__c","Contact.Age__c","Contact.BG_Summary__c","Contact.Birthdate","Contact.City_H__c","Contact.CountryHome__c","Contact.CountryHome__r.Id","Contact.CountryHome__r.Name","Contact.Email","Contact.Gender__c","Contact.Kakao_Talk__c","Contact.Marital_Status__c","Contact.MobilePhone","Contact.NationalityPrimary__c","Contact.NationalityPrimary__r.ISO_2__c","Contact.NationalityPrimary__r.Id","Contact.NationalityPrimary__r.Name","Contact.NationalitySecondary__c","Contact.NationalitySecondary__r.ISO_2__c","Contact.NationalitySecondary__r.Id","Contact.NationalitySecondary__r.Name","Contact.Photo__c","Contact.Picture_ID__c","Contact.State_Province_H__c","Contact.WhatsApp__c","Contact.ZIP_Postalcode_H_del__c","Contact.vfirst__Stage__c","Contact.vfirst__of_Background_Checks_Ordered__c"],"actualFields":["Contact.Id","Contact.Security_Flag__c","Contact.Name","Contact.RecordTypeId"]}'
>   in conflicting record '003f400000nl6InAAI'

There was another post on this, which claimed it was a fixed bug. However, I cannot find it on the Known Issues page on SF.  Curious if anyone knows how to fix this? I'm trying to avoid the usual 5-hour effort it takes to report a bug to Salesforce.

Comment: For reference, the 'expected fields' are always random; and 9/10 times the LC is loaded there are no errors.

Comment: Please make sure you keep your debug mode on and see the vscode warnings .

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty - I've tried this, but the debug doesn't show any error other than the "appendChild is disallowed in Element unless `lwc:dom="manual"` directive is used in the template".  However, this shows on pages where there is no error, and the LC works fine.. I'm a bit lost, I think this is the same as the "Aura Components Bug" that claims to be resolved?

Comment: Need to some more debugging. I am unable to get profile or email from user this was lightning component bug and saesforce told they fixed but it is coming have you logged this issue with salesforce

Comment: I was trying to avoid making a Case with Salesforce, as my experience is each 'case' I make to try and help them costs me 10+ hours of work. Bug reporting is a nightmare.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty - Can you clarify your comment,... it made no sense? Sorry

Comment: I am using standard api wire service to get the profile name and email and it is not allowing me to save the lwc component. It is saying those fields does not exist append __c if those are custom.

Answer (score 0):

We've built a workaround. Namely we catch the error and rewire the data again. Sometimes it is being done 2-3 times but after that everything was loaded and rendered correctly.

It could look like this:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS }) wireObject(result)  {
this.wiredResult = result;

if (result.error && result.error.body.message.indexOf('Missing field(s)') != -1) {
    return refreshApex(this.wiredResult);
}

// ... process result

}
```

ensure please, if the `result.error.body.message` is the correct path

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by adding more detail.